# Why doesn't Aman's wife come back the last time?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, survive-style-5+

In the movie [*Survive Style 5+* (2004)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0430651/combined), Aman's wife comes back as a revengeful ghost every time he kills her. But when she is killed the second time by the hitman, she doesn't come back. What is the difference, and does it play any part in the plot?

Comment: Cruel irony, perhaps? She dies just when he wants her to live again?

Comment: I think it's a metaphor describing how often we only value something (or someone) once it's lost forever.